# Use of PatternLayout class's format(LoggingEvent event) method from a newly created Thread to execute custom log masking logic independently

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, data-masking

Unable to call PatternLayout class's format(LoggingEvent event) method from a newly created Thread to execute custom log masking logic independently without putting any impact on the actual functionlity. Getting multiple errors like -

1. Compiler is asking to make the LoggingEvent object final.
2. Unable to store the masked response into the global variable **maskedOutput** inside run() method, which we want to return from the format(LoggingEvent event) method.

**Below is the actual code:-**

```
public class CardNumberFilteringLayout extends PatternLayout {
    private static final String MASK = "$1++++++++++++";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{9,15})");
    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage() instanceof String) {
            String message = event.getRenderedMessage();
            Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll(MASK);
                @SuppressWarnings({ "ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored" })
                Throwable throwable = event.getThrowableInformation() != null ? 
                        event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable() : null;
                LoggingEvent maskedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.fqnOfCategoryClass,
                        Logger.getLogger(event.getLoggerName()), event.timeStamp, 
                        event.getLevel(), maskedMessage, throwable);
                return super.format(maskedEvent);
            }
        }
        return super.format(event);
    }
}
```

**As per our requirement, we are trying to change the above piece of code into below:-**

```
@Override
public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
    String maskedOutput = null;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            maskedOutput = //Masking Logic(Same As Above)
        } 
    }).start();
    return maskedOutput; 
}
```

Comment: Your `maskedOutput` variable is local, not global. Please edit the question and add what your exact requirement is, because creating a thread and not waiting for it before returning is *wrong*.

Comment: It's hard to see how using a thread to do some work here will help, as you'd need to wait for the task to end in order to pass the value back to the caller of the method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I want to set 'super.format(event);' into a String type variable and want to return the same variable from the format(LoggingEvent event) method. If will declare the variable inside the format(LoggingEvent event) method, then I can easily return the same, but can not use that to assign the result of the masking logic inside run() method as this is not final and if I will make it final then I would not able to assign the result into it. If I will declare the variable under Runnable instance then I can assign the result but would not able to return the same from the above method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I can not declare the variable which I want to return from the in class level, I have format(LoggingEvent event), there are certain restrictions as per our project requirement and yes one more thing is we can not make LoggingEvent object as final, as per our project requirement, but without making LoggingEvent object as final we can not use it inside run() method during masking logic execution. How to execute the masking logic inside run() method without making LoggingEvent as final? How to return the masking logic's result from format(LoggingEvent event) method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, our project's requirement is to mask Personally Identifiable Information (PII) before printing those in the log files like debug.log, error.log, info.log, etc. In our project, we are capturing log messages for each and every functionality that we are performing. But this PII masking logic which we are executing during the log capturing process for each activity takes much time to execute and after the execution of this masking logic and printing masked output into our log files, then the process will complete and will get the output on the screen.

Comment: To avoid the above performance issue during each operation we are performing in our application, we are trying to keep our custom masking logic in a separate Thread so that the masking logic execution will not disturb the current Thread and our application will work smoothly and will get the expected output on the screen within very less time. At the same time in the backend, the dedicated Thread for custom masking logic execution will complete the masking process and will write the masked log messages into corresponding log files without disturbing our main process.

Comment: You should add these long explanation *into* your question, by clicking [edit]. But it sounds like you don't understand how to work with threads. You really shouldn't be using a thread, but rather an executor service. And you should set it up separately and send messages to it.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j 1.2 is **unsupported** since 2015. All modern replacements have some sort of regex substitution support.

In **Log4j 2.x** you can use:

```xml
<PatternLayout pattern="your_pattern">
  <Replace regex="(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})" replacement="$1********$2"/>
</PatternLayout>
```

or

```xml
<PatternLayout pattern="%replace{your_pattern}{(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})}{$1********$2}"/>
```

In **Logback** you can use:

```xml
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
  <pattern>
    %replace(your_pattern){"(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})", "$1********$2"}
  </pattern>
</encoder>
```